# let 'S' be the sample space and 'T' be the complementary event of S. So, will P(S or T) be equal to P(S)?

Tags: probability, random-variable

to prove that P(s) = 1. how do you prove such with venn diagram? because it doesn't make sense that p(s) = P(S or T).

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.  What does your Venn diagram of $S$ and $T$ look like?  Indeed, what set is $T$?  What do the probability axioms tell you $\Pr(S)$ and $\Pr(T)$ should be?  What is the set $S\cup T$?

Comment: The Venn diagram looks like any regular kind, authors use to explain two sets. I've already mentioned that S and T are just the notations I gave for the 'sample space' and 'complementary side of the sample space. The axioms tell that Pr(S) =1 where S can contain any event(s).

Comment: In a Venn diagram, the whole diagram represents the entire sample space and each region in the diagram represents *two* sets: a subset and its complement.  Thus, your diagram needn't have any subregions in it at all: it's just a rectangle representing $S.$  If you prefer, you could indicate a subregion (say, a disk) to represent $S,$ understanding that its complement (its exterior in the rectangle) is *empty.*